# MySQL partition rows by A, within groups sort by B, and then sort all those groups by C of first rows of each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to pull off something like this:

[image]

So, rows are partitioned by column A, inner sorting for each partition is by B. Then, those partitions are stacked together, sorting them by C of first row of each partition. I'm not sure if this is doable?

Comment: "Group" in SQL means something different from what you describe here. Based on the information you have provided, this is simply "ORDER BY A,B,C"

Comment: primary sort should be by C, but the grouping cannot be fractured

Comment: No Milos it should not be "primary sort by C". Look at your table above, Look at just column C. The values are all mixed up. Look at column A. Although not shown here in ascending order, a SORT BY A first will put all the rows with the same value of 'A' together.

Comment: Sorting by C, but only C from first rows of each partition, as highlighted in yellow

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me.  Look at the output of `SELECT A,B,C FROM yourtable ORDER BY A,B,C`. Explain why this does not fulfil your stated  requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order by first_value(c) over (partition by a order by b),
         a,
         b
```

That is, sort by the first value that `c` has in each group, when ordered by `b`.  Then order by `a` -- which keeps all the rows for a given group together.  And finally by `b` within each group.

Comment: thank you Gordon, I've corrected my question as I now learned thanx to you that those are called partitions, not groups :)